# eliminating duplicates in std::vector

Tags: c++, algorithm, stdvector

I have a very large std::vector of std::vectors containing a fixed number of unsigned integers.

All vectors of uints are sorted ascending.

My current way to eliminate duplicate vectors is

```
unsigned int i = 0;
while ( i < new_combs.size() )
{
  unsigned int j = i + 1;
  while ( j < new_combs.size() )
  {
     unsigned int k = 0;
     while ( k < new_combs.at(i).size() && new_combs.at(i).at(k) == new_combs.at(j).at(k) )
        ++k;
     if ( k == new_combs.at(j).size() )
        new_combs.erase(new_combs.begin() + j);
     else
        ++j;
  }
  ++i;
}
```

here, new_combs is a vector containing vectors as mentioned above.

Is there a more efficient way to eliminate duplicates if the vector of vectors is unsorted?

Comment: Duplicate of [Most efficient way to erase duplicates and sort a c++ vector?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1041620/most-efficient-way-to-erase-duplicates-and-sort-a-c-vector)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

A shorter way would be using `<algorithm>`:

```
std::sort(new_combs.begin(), new_combs.end());
new_combs.erase(std::unique(new_combs.begin(), new_combs.end()), new_combs.end());
```

Unless you specifically need a `std::vector`, you can use `std::set` to avoid duplicates.

Comment: isn't sorting also at least O(n²) ?

Comment: @stefan your solution is O(n^2). And std::sort is surprisingly fast.

Comment: i know that my algorithm is O(n²), but thats not an argument for std::sort beeing faster than O(n²) ;-)

Comment: @stefan std::sort is, in worst case, O(n^2). It's a quicksort, which is usually O(n*log(n)).

Comment: @stefan sort is n*log(n) on average.

Answer (score 3):

Have you considered using std::set? It is ordered and doesn't allow duplicates to begin with.

Answer (score 2):

Not much you can do if the vector is unsorted. If it is sorted however you can use the [unique](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/algorithm/unique/) method defined in algorithm:

```
new_combs.erase(unique(new_combs.begin(), new_combs.end()), new_combs.end());
```

Answer (score 0):

There are several elements in your code that ring my alarm bell regarding performance.

First, you are using vectors.  Erasing elements from vectors is always slow.
You might consider using a different container (std::list) or adjust your code so that you have a special value for nothing (e.g. zero or -1).

Second, you could use an std::set or std::unordered_set to keep values that you already encountered.
That way, you only have to loop over your vectors once.

**EDIT:** Forget this answer.  I misread the question and thought that duplicate values (not duplicate vectors) had to be removed.

Nevertheless, some reactions on the comments given:

- @Jerry: I agree that vectors are in most cases faster than lists, but only if the size of the vector is limited.  If the vector contains 1 million elements and you need to remove the 3rd, then the 5th, then the 10th, ... you end up moving lots of elements.  In such a case a list could be faster.
- @James: in the original question, the elements were not removed from the end of the vector, but in the middle.  If the vector is very big (let's say 1 million elements), then removing elements can still become a bottleneck.  However, I agree than using a sort, followed by a unique is probably faster.

Comment: I don't understand what you mean by "have a special value for nothing", my vectors are all of equal size and the size is always greater than 0

Comment: Have you ever actually compared vectors to lists? You might want to read a [previous question](http://stackoverflow.com/q/9764452/179910), including both the answers and the link. Bottom line: even when it should theoretically be superior, list is usually slower than vector.

Comment: Erasing elements from the end of a vector is **not** slow.  Using the solutions with a sorted vector and `std::unique` will probably be considerably faster than using any form of map (which are node based containers, and notoriously slow).

Answer (score 0):

Asymptotically, your algorithm seems like the usual O(n) implementation and is therefore optimal. (Even though I didn't understand your diagonalization strategy with `i` and `j` and why you only erase, but never move elements. Your code is highly unclear.)
However, you are duplicating the STL, and a shorter version of a unique-ing loop is:

```
struct unique {
    template <class C>
    void operator()( C& c ) {
         c.erase( std::unique( c.begin(), c.end() ), c.end() );
    }
};

std::for_each( new_combs.begin(), new_combs.end(), unique() );
```

Comment: why should i move? i don't care about sorting the vector

Comment: @stefan: You want to remove duplicates, and a vector is contiguous, so you'll have to move up some elements at some point.

Answer (score 0):

I agree with [Luchian Grigore's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10088633/533120), but you might also consider converting the whole outer `vector` to `unordered_set`, which is an O(n) operation provided hashes of sub-vectors are not too lopsided (as opposed to average O(n*log(n)) for sorting). You can even use **pointers** to sub-vectors in your `unordered_set`, to avoid unnecessary copying. This can be an important performance difference for large amounts of data.

[This example](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9685502/533120) illustrates the basic idea of using your own hash function and pointers (it deals with `vector` of `string`s and uses `unordered_map`, not `unordered_set`, but you should be able to modify it fairly easily to your needs).