# C++ - Which compiler do I use to get the auto eq = [ ](...) syntax to work?

Tags: c++, xcode, compiler-construction

I am trying to run the *count occurrences of elements in a vector* code listed in the answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9683488/repeated-elements-in-a-stdvector/9685502#9685502).

But I'm running into compile errors in this function:

```
auto h = [](const std::string* s) {
     return std::hash<std::string>()(*s);
};
```

stating `Expected expression` around the `[ ]`. I know this has to do with the compiler.
I'm using `Xcode 5.0.2`, so I have the option to change the compiler (I think).

Then I'm getting another compile error on the line:

```
std::unordered_map<const std::string*, size_t, decltype(h), decltype(eq)> m(v.size(), h, eq);
```

stating `C++ requires a specifier for all declarations` around the `m(v.size(), h, eq)` portion.

**What compiler should I make sure `Xcode` is compiling with in order to get this code to work?**

**Update:**

Is there a particular name for this `auto = [ ](...)` notation that I could google?

Comment: Not sure, but doesn't [tag:xcode] imply [tag:clang]?

Comment: clang 3.1 or later; gcc 4.5 or later; see http://gcc.gnu.org/projects/cxx0x.html and http://clang.llvm.org/cxx_status.html

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ, It used to use GCC by default.

Comment: @chris Thanks for clarifying. I'm not really familiar with Xcode, must be a misleaded personal association of mine ...

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ, Funnily enough, I've never used it myself (probably because I've been secluded to Windows). I just remember seeing that as a point in a recent-ish release.

Comment: Do you know what standard is taking into account? Try to force to C++11, to cover these `lambda` structures and `unordered_map`.

Comment: @wesley.mesquita That did it. Interestingly, the option for `GNU11++` did not work. Only `C++11` Would have thought they would be the same. Put this in an answer, and I'll accept. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do you know what standard is taking into account?

Try to force to C++11, to cover these `lambda` structures and `unordered_map`.